Addressing the issue of loss=nan in LSTM-based Time Series Classification
I am a student trying out deep learning for the first time. Currently, I am working on an LSTM model to classify data based on coordinates and some additional data points. However, I have encountered some issues and would like to seek your advice.
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(max_steps, feature_size)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dense(len(categories), activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

Above is the structure of my model, which is a very basic LSTM model. I have around 300 to 10,000 datas per class and data includes 5 features and 20 to 50 steps. To prevent overfitting, I randomly sample 300 data points from each class. The problem arises when, for certain seeds, the training progresses normally, while for others, it results in loss=nan and the training does not proceed.
I have tried various methods to resolve this issue, but none have been effective so far. Here are the attempts I have made:
Data Upscaling: Increased the number of sample data points by duplicating the insufficient data.
Learning Rate Adjustment: Suspecting that a high learning rate might be causing the issue, I lowered the learning rate.
Use of Leaky ReLU and Gradient Clipping
Batch Size Adjustment
Weight Initialization with he_normal
I am seeking advice on any other potential methods to resolve the current issue where training is only possible for certain seeds. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
